# MATCH AGAINST - inconsistent search results

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "j_diary_all":

```
CREATE TABLE `j_diary_all` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_type` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  `post_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_entry_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `post_upd_flag` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `post_match` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `bikes_tmp_ref` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `bikes_diary_entry` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
  `post_label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `post_content` (`post_content`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8579 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

It contains a FULLTEXT index on the "post_content" field, and the table contains 8,091 rows.

If I run these SQLs:

```
SELECT id, post_content, post_date FROM j_diary_all WHERE MATCH(post_content) AGAINST ('kids' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT id, post_content, post_date FROM j_diary_all WHERE MATCH(post_content) AGAINST ('kids');
SELECT id, post_content, post_date FROM j_diary_all WHERE post_content LIKE '%kids%';
```

They all return 3,186 rows (total = 8,091 rows).

I can't work out why this:

```
SELECT id, post_content, post_date FROM j_diary_all WHERE post_content LIKE '%said%';
```

Returns 358 rows, while neither of these return any rows:

```
SELECT id, post_content, post_date FROM j_diary_all WHERE MATCH(post_content) AGAINST ('said' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT id, post_content, post_date FROM j_diary_all WHERE MATCH(post_content) AGAINST ('said');
```

I'm aware of the 50% rule with MySQL FULLTEXT indexes - I thought using "IN BOOLEAN MODE" gets around that. However, I don't understand why the FULLTEXT searches both return no records.

I've checked the "ft%" MySQL Variables in case that is relevant:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_%';

Variable_name             Value           
------------------------  ----------------
ft_boolean_syntax         + -><()~*:""&|  
ft_max_word_len           84              
ft_min_word_len           4               
ft_query_expansion_limit  20              
ft_stopword_file          (built-in)
```

I have tried variations of "said" via:

```
SELECT id, post_content, post_date FROM j_diary_all WHERE MATCH(post_content) AGAINST ('+said*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT id, post_content, post_date FROM j_diary_all WHERE MATCH(post_content) AGAINST ('+said*');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATCH AGAINST on FULLTEXT index returning no rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132971/match-against-on-fulltext-index-returning-no-rows)

Comment: Sorry - it probably is slightly duplicated, but since I asked the previous question I've found out a few more things, and thought this new question was clearer as it shows the research I've done to try and solve or understand the issue in more detail. I did take into account the answer in the previous question and thought the "IN BOOLEAN MODE" avoids the 50% trap, and also the text I am searching on is not below the "ft_min_word_len" limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`said` is a so called stopword for MyISAM, see [Full-Text Stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) (these words are supposed to be so common in texts that they aren't included in the index).

> To override the default stopword list for MyISAM tables, set the ft_stopword_file system variable.

Comment: Thanks for that. Very interesting!